# Handle formula on java with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

In my code i need to avoid to use the formula when the values where i'm applying the formula are all 0 or null

this is my code:

```
 public void sumTotalOnColumn(int firstRowIdx, int lastRowIdx, int colIdx, XSSFCellStyle cellStyleCurrency,
                                 XSSFRow row) {
    XSSFCell cell;
    cell = row.createCell(colIdx);
    CellReference firstRef = new CellReference(firstRowIdx, colIdx);
    CellReference lastRef = new CellReference(lastRowIdx - 1, colIdx);
    // Check if all rows have a value of 0 before performing the sum operation
    int check = 0;
    for (int i = firstRowIdx; i < lastRowIdx; i++) {
        XSSFCell currentCell = row.getCell(i);
        if (currentCell != null && currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC && currentCell.getNumericCellValue() != 0) {
            check = check + 1;
        }
    } if(check!=0) {
        cell.setCellFormula("SUM(" + firstRef.formatAsString() + ":" + lastRef.formatAsString() + ")");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyleCurrency);
    }else{
        cell.setCellValue(0);
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyleCurrency);
    }
}
```

I tried to add the check but everytime it set 0 even when i got the values inside the other cell, any other way to do it, or to get the sum among the table i want in java so if is 0 i avoid the formula

Comment: What are the results of your debugging? I guess `int check` is never greater than `0`? It is obvious to me that the logic `for (int i = firstRowIdx; i < lastRowIdx; i++) { XSSFCell currentCell = row.getCell(i); ...` is wrong. In this loop `i` is a row index but `row.getCell(i)` thakes it as a cell index always in the same row. Thus `currentCell` always is a cell in this same row but would need to be a cell in same `colIdx` from rows having  index `firstRowIdx` to `lastRowIdx`.